# How to use Doctrine2 from Symfony2 in an existing future-Symfony application?

Tags: symfony, frameworks, doctrine

I don't find any solution through Symfony's docs and google. I find only stuff about starting an application from scratch.

I have a big own-framework application and i want slowly migrate to Symfony2. I have not the convenience to build a new application from scratch.
Until now i cloned the entire symfony folder into my own-framework application's root folder.
I was using Doctrine by directly implementing it, whitout touching Symfony, like following.

```php
<?php
namespace QueryBuild\Helpers;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Listing
{
protected $appConfig;
protected $doctrineEntityManager;

public function __construct(\cConfig $app_config)
{
    $this->setAppConfig($app_config);
    $this->setDoctrineEntityManager();
}

public function setAppConfig($app_config)
{
    $this->appConfig = $app_config;
}

public function setDoctrineEntityManager()
{
    $paths = array(
        $this->getAppConfig()->BasePath() . "/symfony/src/El/Entity/"
    );
    $isDevMode = true;

    // the connection configuration
    $dbParams = array(
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv', // pdo_sqlsrv for mssql
        'host' => $this->getAppConfig()->db->Host,
        'user' => $this->getAppConfig()->db->User,
        'password' => $this->getAppConfig()->db->Password,
        'dbname' => $this->getAppConfig()->db->Database
    );

    // 5th param on false, to NOT use the simple annotation reader. Otherwise annotations are going to be readed wrong. Can be due to server configurations.
    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
    $doctrineEntityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

    $this->doctrineEntityManager = $doctrineEntityManager;
}

public function getAppConfig()
{
    return $this->appConfig;
}

public function getDoctrineEntityManager()
{
    return $this->doctrineEntityManager;
}


}
```

Dont be confused on my namespace, my actual task is to create a query building feature.

Now i don't want anymore to connect to the db by passing the login datas into setDoctrineEntityManager().
I already wrote those informations in **/symfony/app/config/parameters.yml** .
Now my idea was to instanciate symfony to be able to read the configuration, and howewer from symfony to instanciate doctrine.

How can i accomplish this?
Many thanks in advice.

Comment: How are you using symfony together with your application? i.e: How are you bootstrapping symfony? Nothing happens by only 'copying' the files.

Comment: Hi, that's the question, Symfony is not yet used/implemented/instanciated/bootstrapped in my Application. How i can accomplish this, and then how can i get the logged-in doctrine instance?

Comment: There are many different ways for that, you'll have to ask another question. for a start see http://www.slideshare.net/fabrice.bernhard/modernisation-of-legacy-php-applications after slide 19.

Comment: All right, i will check the link, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my solution was the contrary as i thinked before. Symfony2 is now **the wrapping** base application, and the legacy application is (at the moment) encapsulated as a LegacyBundle. Now i can pass e.g. the Entity-Manager or even the Controller-Container to the legacy application.